The phone reboots during a SYN flood test
I tried executing a SYN flood attack through my phone's internet hotspot, but the phone restarts after about 30 seconds. What might be causing this issue?
p.s: I tried using hotspot from other devices

A "SYN flood" sends multiple SYN packets (the initial part of an Internet Protocol SYN->, <-ACK, ->SYN/ACK connection setup), in an attempt to exhaust the target's resources.
All of the SYN packets have to go through your phone, which can't handle the load.
I have run many of the Kali attacks, but always through a wired connection to DSL or better (up to T3 international).
